# Recognize long speech with google api

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

A month ago, I could use google API to recognize long speech about 10 seconds. But today, this api only accepts speech with length not beyond 2 seconds. Anyone can give me a way to recognize long speech.
Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you need to choose other speech recognition API

Comment: See the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689975/google-speech-recognition.

James Grice noted that a changed in google's policy has limited the length.